# Обновление фрагмента в appcompat 1.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

При **appcompat 1.2.0** обновлял фрагмент следующим образом:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(Fragment1.this).attach(Fragment1.this).commit();
```

Теперь перешел на **appcompat 1.3.0** и обновление перестало работать вышеуказанным способом. Также пишет что:  *'getFragmentManager()' is deprecated*.
Пытался использовать *getChildFragmentManager* и *getParentFragmentManager*. Пробовал и через контекст

```
mContext.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(Fragment1.this).attach(Fragment1.this).commit();
```

где

```
    private FragmentActivity mContext; 
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        mContext = (FragmentActivity) context;
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
```

К сожалению, ничего не помогло. Подскажите как мне обновлять фрагмент с appcompat 1.3.0?

Comment: решение по этой ссылке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66498713/how-to-refresh-android-fragment-v1-3-0-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Сначала детачим, а потом аттачим фрагмент:

```
getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(Fragment1.this).commitNow();
```

```
getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(Fragment1.this).commitNow();
```